# Showing the title bar

Tags: android, titlebar

I have an app that switches between full screen and normal screen for a certain condition. 
                 I have successfully done this with the notification but the TITLE BAR still remains hidden after I set it back from full screen to normal screen mode. So HOW DO I SHOW THE TITLE BAR AFTER HIDING IT?

EDIT:

I have come across answers where they make a custom title bar and switch between its visibility but thats not what I want.

CODE:

```
if(ScreenReceiver.wasScreenOn) {
    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "screen was on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.resume);
} else { 
    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "screen was off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: where you have added this code?

Comment: in the onresume....I dont have a problem with this code...just wanna add the title bar when first condition in if-loop is executed

Comment: your code works perfectly for me.

Comment: and did you notice the title bar disappearing?

Comment: works perfectly means Yes I can see.

Comment: I haven't added anything extra in the hide/show Title, its your code only.

Comment: this code hides the title bar and notification bar on purpose in the second condition. Now in the first condition the code shows the notification bar but not the title bar..could you tell me how its done?

Comment: it hides both notification and title(FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
 this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


/// custom tittle bar declaration 
final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

/// custom tittle bar creation ///....
    if (customTitleSupported) {
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.tittle_bar);
    }
    final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_bar);
    if (myTitleText != null) {
        myTitleText.setText("Categories");
    }
```